# Using RMysql's dbGetQuery in R, how do i coerce string data type on the result set?

Tags: mysql, r

RMysql's dbGetQuery converts BigInt to numeric types. This alters some of the values. How can I read the BigInt fields as strings instead of numeric?

Comment: Very interested in learning more about this. I would appreciate if the experts would also give some good references (I am working my way through "Data Manipulation in R" by Spector).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to cast on the SQL side of things:

```
select cast(foo as char), bar from someTable;
```

You may have to look up the exact [MySQL casting syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html) for details.

[ By the way, there is no tag [rstats] here. ]

Comment: thanks, that does work but i think you mean: cast(foo as char)